# how to add extra element to array with array_push in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am developing in PHP/MS SQL for getting JSON Response.

Code which I wrote is:

```
while( $result = sqlsrv_fetch_object($sql_Gpo_Carr)) {

      $array_res[] = $result;                           // add result to array
      array_push($array_res, array('unidad' => $uni));  // add extra element
      $jsonObj = json_encode($array_res);               // encode JSON 
   }    

echo $jsonObj;

     exit();
```

This is what I want in result:

```
[{"idperiodo":"37","idgrupo":"1963","idhorario":"12832","unidades":null,"unidad":1}]
```

but the result shows me this:

```
[{"idperiodo":"37","idgrupo":"1963","idhorario":"12832","unidades":null},{"unidad":1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fetching an object.  Add `$uni` to `$result` first and then add to `$array_res`:

```
while( $result = sqlsrv_fetch_object($sql_Gpo_Carr)) {
    $result->unidad = $uni;
    $array_res[] = $result;
}
```

Also, you probably want the `json_encode()` after the loop not in the loop:

```
echo json_encode($array_res);
```